# GStreamer missing plugins on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, plugins, gstreamer

I have installed the latest version of gstreamer (v1.16.2) on a Windows 10 with a full installation and testing simple examples I have checked that several common elements are missing.

With a command like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I receive this log:

```
GST_INIT gst.c:810:init_post: initialized GStreamer successfully
GST_PIPELINE gstparse.c:337:gst_parse_launch_full: parsing pipeline description 'videotestsrc ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink '
GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:462:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "videotestsrc"!
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "videotestsrc"
GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:462:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "capsfilter"!
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "capsfilter"
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:901:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0000000000000000]
GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:462:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "videoconvert"!
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "videoconvert"
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:901:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0000000000000000]
GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY stelementfactory.c:462:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "autovideosink"!
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "autovideosink"
GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:901:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0000000000000000]
```

I also have checked that the installer creates a new environment variable **GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86_64** pointing to **C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64** and it also adds the **bin** folder to the **Path**.

Does the MSI installer need any additional step to register its plugins on a Windows Machine ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the issue and it's solution. At least on Windows... Gstreamer generates a bin file with the list of registered plugins. This file is stored in this path

```
C:\Users\<name_of_user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\gstreamer-1.0\registry.x86_64.bin
```

It seems that there was an issue in the first launch and the list of plugins was broken. If you delete this bin file and launch any command over **gst-launch-1.0** it checks again all its own plugins and it refreshes that bin file.